# Tooltipster not working very first time

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

I am using tooltipster in my gridview buttons to show dynamically generated table on mouseover event of button. But it is not working very first time and afterwards it works.
Here is my code:

```
 var jobid1 = '';
    var salesofficeid1 = '';
    function ShowMe(event, jobid, SalesOfficeId) {
        jobid1 = jobid;
        salesofficeid1 = SalesOfficeId;
        $('.reviewNotes').tooltipster({
            multiple: true,                
            functionBefore: function (origin, continueTooltip) {
                continueTooltip();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    url: 'Mywebservice.asmx/FetchReviewHistory',
                    data: "{ 'jobid':" + jobid1 + ",'SalesOfficeId':" + salesofficeid1 + "}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        origin.tooltipster('content', $(data.d));
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

Onmouseover event of my button I am calling function ShowMe().
I tried to find answer of my question everywhere, but my issue is not still resolved.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tooltipster adds the hover event listener for you so you need to run tooltipster on `document.ready`.

What is essentially happening in your case is when a user hovers over it adds a hover listener. It won't be until the second time that you hover that you notice the tooltipster. This is also bad because you add an extra hover event listener every time you hover.